# How to disable canvas scaling

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

This question was asked many times in Stackoverflow, but still I got no answer that does work for me. I have a canvas that I draw on using WebGL and I would like to prevent user from scaling/zooming it (i.e. from changing its size, e.g. by pitch gesture on Mac). Instead I want to handle it programmatically (via "wheel" event?) and implement "logical" scaling of its content. I know that it's possible (see how Google Maps handles zooming).

Answer (score 0):

Google maps have this in head:

```html
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Key is [use-scalable](https://web.dev/meta-viewport/#:%7E:text=The%20user%2Dscalable%3D%22no,contents%20of%20a%20web%20page.):

```
user-scalable=no
```

[From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114830/how-to-prevent-native-browser-default-pinch-to-zoom-behavior)

```js
element.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
   const { ctrlKey } = event
   if (ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return
   }
}, { passive: false })
```

Comment: That doesn't work on my Mac, I'm still able to scale the page using pitch gesture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458954/prevent-pinch-zoom-in-safari-for-osx